# When $E$ has finite dimension, then the weak topology and the strong topologie are the same.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, weak-topology

Let $E$ a normed vector space of finite dimension. Then the strong topology and the weak topology are the same. To prove it, we take $x_0\in E$ and $U$ an open set (for the strong topology) that contain $x_0$. Then we have to prove that it's an open set for the weak topology, i.e. that there is $V$ weakly open s.t. $V\subset U$. Do do, in my book it's written that we have to find a finite sequence $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ of $E'$ and an $\varepsilon>0$ s.t. $$V=\{x\in E : \forall i\in I|,\left<f_i, x-x_0\right>|<\varepsilon\}\subset U.$$

**My questions :** Why we need only a finite sequence $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ to describe $V$ ? Shouldn't it be $$V=\{x\in E : \forall f\in E', |\left<f_i, x-x_0\right>|<\varepsilon\}.$$

Comment: I guess you want $(f_i)$ and $\varepsilon>0$ s.t. $V\subset U$ (I add this last inclusion)

Answer (score 1):

No, $I$ is finite since the subbasis for the weak topology is $$\mathcal S:=\{f^{-1}(U)\mid f\in E', U\text{ open in }\mathbb F\}.$$
Therefore, the basis is given by finite intersection of element of $\mathcal S$, i.e. an element of the basis is $$\bigcap_{\substack{i\in I \\ |I|<\infty }}f_{i}^{-1}(U_i),$$
where $U_i$ are open an $f_i\in E'$.

Comment: Shouldn't it say $\mathcal S:=\{f^{-1}(U)\mid f\in E', U\text{ open in }\mathbb{F}\}.$ for $\mathbb{F}$ being $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$; because $f^{-1}$ maps from the base field $\mathbb{F}$ to E?

Comment: Sure I edited it, thank you. But notice that $f^{-1}$ doesn't map $\mathbb F\to E$ since $f^{-1}$ as a function is not well defined a priori. But since $f:E\to \mathbb F$, then, indeed, we need $f^{-1}(U)$ to be open whenever $U\subset \mathbb F$ is open. @Valentin